# Deleting blank Gift Aids

Tags: gift-aid-extension

We had an issue with one of our forms and so we now need to delete a load of gift aid declarations from CiviCRM that are blank. Is there anyway we can do this in bulk rather than doing it manually.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use API4 explorers

/civicrm/api4#/explorer/Custom_Gift_Aid_Declaration/delete

Or via the searchkit

/civicrm/admin/search#/create/Custom_Gift_Aid_Declaration?params=%7B"version":4,"select":%5B"id","Eligible_for_Gift_Aid:label","Start_Date","End_Date","Reason_Ended:label","Source","Notes","name_of_charity","High_Rate_Tax_Payer:label","Declaration_Method:label","Gift_Aid_confirmation_date_1"%5D,"orderBy":%7B%7D,"where":%5B%5D,"groupBy":%5B%5D,"join":%5B%5D,"having":%5B%5D%7D

Comment: Thanks Pradeep. That's a little too advanced for me. Guess there's no easier way?

Comment: You could build a searchkit and delete all the records

Comment: Thanks so much Pradeep. i have managed to fix it thanks to you!